# How to set errorPlacement after form-group in Yii2

Tags: validation, yii2, kartik-v, active-form

How can I set errorPlacement in Yii2 activeform or using kartik active form just after form-group?
Below are code for view file.

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
     <div class="form-group field-signupform-value1 required">
          <label class="control-label" for="signupform-value1">value1 Name</label>
          <input type="text" id="signupform-value1" class="form-control" name="SignupForm[value1]" placeholder="value1 Name" aria-required="true">
           <p class="help-block help-block-error"></p>
      </div> 
</div>
```

I want html code as below.

should auto add after .

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
     <div class="form-group field-signupform-value1 required">
          <label class="control-label" for="signupform-value1">value1 Name</label>
          <input type="text" id="signupform-value1" class="form-control" name="SignupForm[value1]" placeholder="value1 Name" aria-required="true"> 
      </div> 
    <p class="help-block help-block-error"></p> 
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: any reason why you want to change the placement?

Comment: as my form design required error label should display just after form-group

Comment: what do you mean by after form group? do you mean at the top of the form? at bottom? can you show us a screenshot of your design, where actually you want to show an error message?

Comment: @NitinPund, I have already pasted html code in my post. Can you please check there?

Comment: looking at the screenshot, you don't need to change its placement

Comment: My requirement is want to show error div after that border box.

Comment: refer updated answer... just add template with div and css class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your inputs, it is not needed to change the replacement of the error message, though if you want to play with the input template properties, you can refer the following

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
          'fieldConfig'=>['template'=>'<div style="border:solid 1px black;padding-bottom:15px">{label}{input}{hint}</div>{error}']

]); ?>
```

in the above template properties, you can change the placement of error template or event add some HTML inside it, hope it will help you.

**Edit:**
I have added inline css to div, you can put your css class which is applying outer border.

Answer (score 1):

I achieved by below code. Thank for kind suggestion.

```
<?php 
$form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'fieldConfig'=>['template'=>' <div class="custom"> 
    {label}{input}
</div>
{error}',
'inputOptions' => [
'placeholder' => 'Username ...',
'class'=>'form-control',
]]
 ]); ?>
```

and given css to "custom" class for border-box

Answer (score 0):

You can use another hidden input like this:

```
$form->field($model, "your_field")->hiddenInput([
                     'class' => 'hidden_input_val'
                  ])->label(false) //  (for validation messages)
```

To display error in HTML:

```
<?=Html::error($model, 'your_field', ['class' => 'help-block']) ?>
```

Then you just have to hide this hidden input's .help-block with css